# How to find Contract ID by interface name?

Tags: firefox-addon, xpcom

Example: I want to use the interface of `nsILocalFile` in Javascript, how to find the corresponding Contract `ID("@mozilla.org/file/local;1")`? Is there a map in the source code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't. This isn't a one-to-one relationship between contracts and interfaces but a many-to-many one:

- A single component as accessible by a contract can implement multiple interfaces.
- A single interface can have multiple components implementing it and therefore multiple contracts.

But, often it is a one-to-one relationship in practice. E.g. if I wanted to find out about what components implement `nsILocalFile`, I'd search it in the sources, for instance:

- MXR: http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/ident?i=nsILocalFile&tree=mozilla-central
- A glance over the result list already tells me: `line 1255 -- let file = Cc["@mozilla.org/file/local;1"].createInstance(Ci.nsILocalFile);`
- Else I'd have to look at the files the different results link, starting with the `.js` ones.

Other times, the contract ids are even specified in the idl itself, e.g. in [`nsITimer.idl`](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/xpcom/threads/nsITimer.idl) (at the bottom).

The most commonly used interfaces usually are also present on MDN incl. contracts, e.g. [`nsILocalFile`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsILocalFile).